# When Exactly Should Atomicity be used? When is it Really Useful?

Tags: java, atomic

I want to know at which cases exactly should be used **atomicity**?

For example:

```
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
```

may be

```
AtomicReference<StringBuffer> buffer = new AtomicReference<>(new StringBuffer());
```

But when it is really useful? Can somebody explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need `AtomicReference` when you have to update a reference which needs to be updated by a set of threads and read by other threads.

For instance, consider a processing job whose description and status is represented by some `JobReport` class; you have some threads processing a queue of jobs, and when one thread completes a job, it creates a `JobReport` object; in another set of threads, you want to know at one point in time, and as accurately as possible, which job was last processed: you need the latest `JobReport`.

In this case, all of these threads will share an `AtomicReference<JobReport>`; processing threads will write to it the report of the job they have just completed, while the reading, reporting threads will read from that reference.

(well, when I say "need"... There are other solutions to that scenario, but this is one of them)

Answer (score 2):

`AtomicReference` is about making two-three distinct operations *on the reference itself* execute atomically, such as `compareAndSet`, `getAndSet`, and others. It is not at all about the atomicity of operations on the referent (the object referred to by the reference).